# How to Combine Month and Year of Data frame to Time Series Data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have global temperature dataset of the following format:

YEAR JAN    FEB    MAR    APR    MAY    JUN    JUL    AUG    SEP    OCT    NOV    DEC

1880 -0.30  -0.21  -0.18  -0.28  -0.14  -0.29  -0.24  -0.08  -0.17  -0.16  -0.19  -0.22

1881 -0.09  -0.14  0.01   -0.03  -0.04  -0.28  -0.06  -0.02  -0.08  -0.19  -0.26  -0.15

1882 0.10   0.09   0.02   -0.20  -0.17  -0.25  -0.10   0.04  -0.01  -0.22  -0.21  -0.25

.
.
.
etc

I want to make it like time series data like following format:

[-0.30  -0.21  -0.18  -0.28  -0.14  -0.29  -0.24  -0.08  -0.17  -0.16  -0.19  -0.22  -0.09  -0.14  0.01   -0.03  -0.04  -0.28  -0.06  -0.02  -0.08  -0.19  -0.26  -0.15 0.10   0.09   0.02   -0.20  -0.17  -0.25  -0.10   0.04  -0.01  -0.22  -0.21  -0.25 ... etc]

I've been trying to use df.stack() function, but not getting the result that I want

please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `YEAR` column before calling `stack`:

```py
df.drop(columns="YEAR").stack().to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked for my problem:

```
from pandas import read_csv

data = []
df = read_csv('file.csv', usecols=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
df['Temp'] = df.values.tolist()
df = df['Temp'].values.tolist()
df =  [j for sub in df for j in sub]
df =  df[:1639]
for element in df:
    data.append(float(element))

print(data)
```